# Rewrite/change object to change references without setters

Tags: java, pointers, reference

I am having a trouble figuring out whether it is possible to change all references without using class setters methods.
I am also limited to java.util.* methods.

Imagine this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Apple> first = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Apple> second = new ArrayList<>();

    Apple someApple = new Apple(5);
    first.add(someApple);
    second.add(someApple);



    Apple changeIt = first.get(0);
    // Is it possible to change / rewrite object changeIt (no class setters available)

}


public static class Apple {
    int size;

    public Apple (int size){
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

}
```

The goal is to change same object in `List<Apple> second`. I dont have direct access to `List<Apple> second` nor class setters.

edit>
Maybe this code explains the situation a bit better:

```
List<Obj> doSomething = cantTouch.getUseThis();

public class Obj {
    var SomeVariables;
    public Obj(){}
}

public class cantTouch {
    private static List<Obj> tryToModify = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<Obj> useThis = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void createObj() {
        Obj someObj = new Obj();
        tryToModify.add(someObj);
        useThis.add(someObj);
    }

    public static List<Obj> getUseThis(){
        return useThis;
    }
}
```

Comment: The lists don't contain objects. They contain references to objects. Your example shows both lists containing references to the same object. If you called a mutator method on the one object through either reference, that one object would be changed. If you changed the reference in one list, it would not automatically change the reference in the other list.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to edit private fields of an object but there is no public method to do that, you could use *Reflections* (google it). However this is usually a bad idea, as it bypasses class-internal logics that might exist (for example, sanity checks on the value that is tried to be assigned, or internal updates to other fields that might related to the field that you change)

To find the best solution, please explain in more detail what your situation is. Why can you not have a setter for the field? Is it some third-party library where you don't have the sources for?

Comment: Well, the situation is given to me as is. The task says i can not modify any of the code. I have to modify object references that are stored in `private` variable. I only have an access to these objects by references in another array, in which an object was added upon creation (as in the code above).

Comment: I'm not yet sure if me or you have understood the task correct. Just to make sure: Do you have to change the reference in the second list, i.e. replace the object in the second list with another object, or do you need to modify the object itself (e.g. the "size" field for your apple in your first example)? And if the latter, do you have access to the "size" field or not?

Comment: In my case it does not matter whether to change or replace the object. Yes, i have to change the object in the second list. I thought that since **i do not have set access to `size`** my only option is to replace the object with new properties.

Comment: well, you cannot edit the object and you cannot edit the list. For me it sounds like there's nothing you can do. Again, the only technical way I know of is editing the object field via reflection. But you said you can only use the java.util.* package? So, sorry, I'm out of ideas

Comment: That is fine, still thank you. Anyway, reflections is a nice thing a have never heard of.